# D&D Probability question: why am I wrong?

Tags: probability, simulation, odds, dice

In Dungeons and Dragons, the primary die used for success or failure is the D20, or 20 sided die.  A 1 is a critical failure, and a 20 is a critical success.  When one has advantage, one rolls 2 dice and takes the higher of the 2 rolls.  Recently, we had a game where a character rolled 6 critical successes over the course of 18 rolls, some with advantage and some without. The odds of a critical success by itself are 1 in 20 (p1), the odds with advantage are 39 in 400 (p2). What are the odds of 6 over the course of 18 rolls?

I modelled it as 18 choose 6 / pn^6. This yielded 1 in 3500 for p1 and 1 in 62 for p2. I also wrote a simulation, and got significantly different results, but in the ballpark. I rolled a billion simulations and the results converged to about 1/6300 for p1 and 1/220 for p2. I repeated this several times with essentially no change.

Where did I go wrong? I would really like to know why these 2 methods don't yield similar results.

Comment: The formula should be not $^{18}C_6{p_n}^6$, but $^{18}C_6{p_n}^6(1-p_n)^{12}$

Comment: @Dave: I agree about disagreeing with the close vote. I would say questions like these are squarely on-topic in the [tag:probability] and [tag:dice] tags, though they might once in a while cross over into [tag:self-study] territory.

Comment: 1. You seem to be using the word *odds* as if it meant the same as *probability*. They are related but are not synonyms. See the Wikipedia page on odds. 2. It wouldn't be hard to specify that you're rolling a 20 sided die , that rolling a 20 is a critical, and that advantage means taking the higher of two such rolls - then you would not cut out people who did not already know these facts from the pool of potential answerers.

Comment: @Glen_b IMO "the odds are 1 in 20" is acceptable colloquial English. It wouldn't be appropriate in academic writing but is fine and unambiguous for this kind of informal discussion.

Comment: It would leave an unnecessary ambiguity or  confusion in many situations. By analogy, while people commonly conflate some combination of force, momentum and kinetic energy in ordinary language, if I did so posting to physics.SE I would  expect (and indeed *want*) to be corrected, since -among other things- that helps for finding answers in the future.

Comment: @fblundun

$$\small{\text{probability} = \frac{\text{the number of chances whereby an event may happen}}{\text{the number of all the chances whereby it may either happen or fail}}}$$


$$\small{\text{odds} = \frac{\text{the number of chances whereby an event may happen}}{\text{the number of chances whereby it may fail}}}$$

The phrase "the odds are 1 to 20" is fine but it means something else from "the probability is 1 in 20".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s a simple binomial distribution problem which gives the number of successes among n trials. You can use the pmf to find the probabilities like so:
(18 choose 6) * p^6 *(1- p)^12
should yield the same answers as your simulation